# range.formula issues

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range

Hello to every one i have next question, i have this code:

```
Public Function AsentamientosCA(celda As String, cotaInst As Single, Zona As String, DensidadZona As Single, _
                                alturaLlenobajocelda As Single, PB As Boolean)

set ws= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hojaDestino")
RangoFechaAs = "A7:A" & DatosFechaL.Rows.Count + 6
ws.Range(Replace(RangoFechaAs, "A", "F")).Formula = "=C7 -" & cotaInst & "-(D7/100)"

End Function

Sub test()

dim celda As String, cotaInst As Single, Zona As String, DensidadZona As Single
dim alturaLlenobajocelda As Single, PB As Boolean

cotaInst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("a").Range("A2").Value
''CotaInst = 240.2 in my pc
'' in other computers CotaInst = 240,2

call AsentamientosCA(400, cotaInst, "2A", 21, 90, True)
End Sub
```

In my pc works great but when i share this code in other pc, fails, and it fails exactly because ***cotaInst*** in my pc is taken as 240.2 meanwhile in other pc is taken as 240,2 is there a way to change this variable, assumming is a single external variable in my code?

because i want this formula run in whatever pc that has macros. I Appreciate your helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening becuase of different reginoal settings. In your pc the decimal separator is `.` whereas in the other pc it is `,`. Try the following (**Untested**)

Here I changed `cotaInst As Single` to `cotaInst As String` and added couple of lines to check for the decimal separator.

```
Sub test()
    Dim celda As String, cotaInst As String, Zona As String, DensidadZona As Single
    Dim alturaLlenobajocelda As Single, PB As Boolean
    Dim decSep As String

    decSep = Application.DecimalSeparator

    cotaInst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("a").Range("A2").Value

    If decSep = "." Then cotaInst = Replace(cotaInst, ",", ".")

    Call AsentamientosCA(400, cotaInst, "2A", 21, 90, True)
End Sub


Public Function AsentamientosCA(celda As String, _
                                cotaInst As String, _
                                Zona As String, DensidadZona As Single, _
                                alturaLlenobajocelda As Single, PB As Boolean)

    RangoFechaAs = "A7:A" & DatosFechaL.Rows.Count + 6
    ws.Range(Replace(RangoFechaAs, "A", "F")).Formula = "=C7 -" & cotaInst & "-(D7/100)"
End Function
```

Comment: Sir thank you for your answer i have a question, in the conditional decSep should be "," ? because formula use english convention right?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the cell will have "," as decimal separator in the other pc

Comment: yeah that's right but when the other pc has "," separator fails. my question is if the other pc has "," as separator decimal when i use the conditional that's that would change no? i mean if decsep = "," that's must be the conditional or not?

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean. Reverse it and try it

Comment: thank you sir i will try! thank you for your answer additional question using range.formula is one of the faster ways to define an operation in colums right?

Comment: Sorry I di dnto understand with what you mean by `define an operation in colums`

Comment: operation in columns if i want in a defined range (columns in my case) the fast way to make an operation is using this case and no for cycle

Comment: If you mean entering formulas is one go then they this is the fastest way.